# Why is this tcsh shell script giving the error while setting PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: shell, scripting, tcsh

I have created a tcsh shell script as follows:

```
#!/bin/tcsh

setenv PATH  ""
setenv PATH  .:$HOME/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:$PATH

setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH ""
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH .:/usr/local/cuda/lib:/usr/local/cuda/lib64/:/usr/local/cuda:/usr/lib:/usr/lib32:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/lib/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}
```

Then I have made this script executable and when I try to execute it as

./script.sh, it gives following errors:

script.sh: 3: setenv: not found

script.sh: 4: setenv: not found

script.sh: 6: setenv: not found

script.sh: 7: setenv: not found

Any pointers, how to set these paths in my shell script?

Comment: Works find on my box. Is your your `tcsh` really what it claims to be? `/bin/tcsh --version`?

Comment: @Shawn - /bin/tchs --version gives: tcsh 6.17.02 (Astron) 2010-05-12 (x86_64-unknown-linux) options wide,nls,dl,al,kan,rh,nd,color,filec

Comment: There was an answer posted to this question but it is deleted now( i don ot know why), which linked to http://www.the4cs.com/~corin/acm/tutorial/unix/tcsh-help.html.  which gives me another question - If I have a Environment variable $PATH set in my .cshrc using setenv PATH .: <my folders here> And then like I am doing in this shell script I set a variable with same name, using set PATH = <something else>, which would take precedence, the environment variable or SHELL variable? Whats the difference between the two, if any?

Comment: `set` defines local variables while `setenv` defines environment variables that will be inherited by subshells. Just as in bash you would use `export` to export a variable as an env var.

Comment: What shell are you using in your terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't get the same error on my system.

**UPDATE :** See the last two paragraphs for my best guess about what's going on.

My initial best guess was that you can fix the problem by changing shebang

```
#!/bin/tcsh
```

to

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f
```

(Or use

```
#!/bin/csh -f
```

The features that tcsh adds to the original csh are mostly useful for interactive use rather than scripting.)

The `-f` option tells tcsh *not* to process your `.login` and `.cshrc` or `.tcshrc` files when it starts up.  Generally you don't want a script to do this; it makes the script's behavior dependent on your own environment setup.  Perhaps you have something in your `.login` that does something odd with `setenv`, though I can't think of what it might be.  Try adding the `-f` and see if that helps.  Even if it doesn't, you should do that anyway.

(And don't use `-f` for `/bin/sh` or `/bin/bash` scripts; it means something else, and isn't needed.)

Some other observations:

Setting `$PATH` and `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the empty string is useless.  Just delete those two lines.

**EDIT :**

On re-reading your question, I see what you're doing there.  You set `$PATH` to the empty string, and then prepend more text to it:

```
setenv PATH ""
setenv PATH this:that:$PATH
```

That makes more sense than I thought it did, but it's still simpler to write one command:

```
setenv PATH this:that
```

Putting `.` in your `$PATH`, *especially* at the beginning, is a bad idea.  Think about what happens if your run the script in a directory where someone has deposited a command name `ls` that does something nasty.  If you want to execute a command in the current directory, use `./command`.  (Putting `.` at the *end* of `$PATH` is safer, but still not a very good idea.)

(And using tcsh or csh as a scripting language (as opposed to an interactive shell) is widely considered to be a bad idea as well.  [This article](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/), even if it doesn't persuade you to give up on tcsh scripting, will at least make you aware of the pitfalls.)

Oh, and if it's a tcsh script, why do you call it `script.sh`?  Suffixes on file names aren't required under Unix-like systems (unlike Windows), but usually a `.sh` suffix implies that it's a Bourne shell script.  Call it `script.tcsh`, or `script.csh`, or just `script`.

**EDIT :**

Taking a closer look at the error message you're getting, it looks like the errors are coming from `/bin/sh`, *not* from tcsh.

On my system, when I change `setenv` to `Setenv` (a nonexistent command), running the script with tcsh gives me:

```
Setenv: Command not found.
Setenv: Command not found.
Setenv: Command not found.
Setenv: Command not found.
```

which doesn't match the error messages you showed us.  When I run it explicitly as `/bin/sh foo.tcsh` (leaving the `setenv` commands alone), I get:

```
foo.tcsh: 3: setenv: not found
foo.tcsh: 4: setenv: not found
foo.tcsh: 6: setenv: not found
foo.tcsh: 7: setenv: not found
```

which does match the format of the errors you got.

You say that `/bin/tcsh --version` gives correct results, so that's not the problem.  Somehow the script is being executed by `/bin/sh`, not by tcsh.

Here's my best guess about what's going on.  You're running on Cygwin, or maybe MSYS, but you're invoking your script from a `cmd` shell, not from a Cygwin shell.  Your Windows system has been configured to recognize a `.sh` suffix to indicate that the file is a script to be executed by `C:\cygwin\bin\sh.exe` (as I mentioned before, file suffixes don't usually matter on Unix, or in the Cygwin environment, but they do on Windows).

The simplest solution would probably be to rewrite the script to conform to Bourne shell syntax.  But there should be ways to cause Windows to invoke Cygwin's `tcsh` to execute it.  If I've guess right, let us know and we can probably come up with a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with your script. It works fine on my box.

The only reason for that error (that I can think of) is `tcsh` is somehow not being used as the interpreter.

I can reproduce the error if I add a line feed before `#!/bin/tcsh`. When the shebang is not the first chars in the file, the interpreter directive does not take effect and your current shell is used (I'm guessing your sheel is not c-shell variant (csh or tcsh)?).

So, check that `#!/bin/tcsh` is indeed the first line in the file, with no whitespace before.

---

To determine which interpreter is actually being used, try adding this to your script:

```
echo "$shell"  ## prints shell name if tcsh or csh
echo "$BASH"   ## prints /bin/bash if bash
```

example:

```
[me@home]$ bash x.sh  # run using bash

/bin/bash

[me@home]$ tcsh x.sh # run using tcsh
/bin/tcsh
BASH: Undefined variable.
```

Comment: I checked, #! is the first line in the script file. Pls check my latest comment above. Do you have any pointers based on that info/questions in the comment

Comment: I'm still thinking tcsh is not being use by your script. does it work as expected if you run it using `/bin/tcsh script.sh`?

Answer (score 1):

just hit this problem, and it turned out to be due to the script file having Windows EOLs.  Once i cleaned it up, all was good.